# API V4 - Uncaught Exception: Authorization failed

Tags: apiv4

With this code I created contact, but only when I'm authorized.

```
        civicrm_api4('Contact', 'create', [
            'values' => [
                'contact_type' => 'Individual',
                'checkPermissions' => false,
                'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'display_name' => $_POST['username'],
            ],
        ]);
```

**But when I'm logout:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkPermissions line should be outside the values array. You can use http://{your-site}/civicrm/api4 to use the explorer to construct the correct code.

```
        civicrm_api4('Contact', 'create', [
            'values' => [
                'contact_type' => 'Individual',
                'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'display_name' => $_POST['username'],
            ],
            'checkPermissions' => false,
        ]);
```